# Value of input type="file" changes in Firefox for android mobile

Tags: javascript, firefox, html-input

Steps to reproduce:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file_name" />
```

1. press button for taking input.
2. In Firefox for Android, select some file name, f.e. "test.mp4".

Actual results:
Name of input file (files[0].name) will be changed to

`tmp_<RandoNo-><FileName><RandomNo>`.

Expected results:
Name of input file (files[0].name) should be `test.mp4`

How can I get the original name of file?

Comment: What gets sent to the server when you submit the form?

Comment: @Barmar: I am using this input to open a video in browser. My video is being played correctly, but if I print the name of the video file, some random text/numbers are getting added to the original file name. Internally browser recognizes the correct video, that's why plays it perfectly. But I need the name of the file as well.

Comment: I have a feeling it's related to the Android OS, when you access a file it copies it to a temporary file, and that's what's in the variable.

Comment: It doesn't happen with Chrome for android. I noticed it only in Firefox. Can there be a way to get the original file name?